# using Make in linux

Tags: c, makefile, command

What exactly does the "make" command in linux do? If I have a makefile, does that correspond with it? when I execute my code, I type make in command and it runs but don't really know what exactly it does. If you could explain to me what's going on i'd be more familiar when doing it in the future, Thanks!

Comment: Type `make clean` and `make -n`.  The first command would perform a cleanup of what was done earlier (assuming the target exists in the Makefile).  The second one doesn't actually *execute* the commands but simply *lists* those.  For more, refer to the [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Answer (score 2):

When using unfamiliar commands in Unix, you can usually type `man <name-of-command>` and you'll get output like this: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?make (You can also google man  and get an online version if not on a Unix platform).

This is called a man-page, and is one of the most predominant forms of documentation for Unix programs.

To answer your original questions, yes `make` uses a `Makefile`. Essentially `make` reads the `Makefile`, and then determines a set of commands to create new files. If you want to understand a little more about make/Makefiles, check out the documentation: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefiles.html

Answer (score 0):

The make command offers a DSL (domain specific language), specialized for expression of algorithms for building things efficiently. The core programming model allows expression of dependencies. A programmer expresses a series of dependencies. Given these dependencies, when something changes, the make program can determine the minimal set of entities that must be built, and in what order. It then executes the rules (that the programmer also states) to build these entities.

In addition to the language that supports this core programming model for expressing dependencies, there are other constructs available like variables, functions, text transformation functions etc. that come in useful in this domain of building things. But its mostly about expressing dependencies and algorithms to build things.